# Is it possible to Dual Boot Ubuntu and use it as a File server?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, server, partitioning

So I'm working on creating a file server or some sort of storage to store content in since I got tired of having to deal with Google Plus' limited 15GB. I have this 5 year old PC lying around along with Hard drives in them, so I thought why not.

Problem is, I don't know what to do. I have family data on those drives in which I want to be accessible in this network, but I hear that doing a fresh install of a Linux Distro wipes the drive completely. I don't want that.

I thought about doing a dual boot to compensate for this, but I am honestly not sure if that will work, and I don't want to risk losing precious family data over a dumb mistake.

Also, is Ubuntu good for what I am trying to do? On the side I'd like to play around with Linux, but before I fully do this I want to know if i'm using the correct distro for it.

Comment: Yes, but don't forget this is a Q&A site & not a forum. Your question is too broad for this site. You can install without being destructive, I did a *install alongside* (ie. existing partition was shrunk & I installed into space created), *replace partition* (OS on partition got replaced), *install using existing partition* (re-install into existing partition without touching any data, additional packages installed by user get auto-reinstalled so it updates the system is the effect), & a *full disk install* (which is destructive to all on disk).

Comment: The installer selects what they do, be it non-destructive or destructive. Backups are essential though as it's easy to make a mistake.  Ubuntu to me is a GNU/Linux, and ~any GNU/Linux will do what you want/need.  Ubuntu has ~good support which is a benefit, but I'd decide using more details than you provided as to which I'd use; but to me your question belongs on a forum, not Q&A site. I can't given my *opinions* here (they're off-topic unless the *solve* your problem in an answer; things to consider are not answers).

Comment: Keep in mind that when you dual-boot, one OS is available for use while the other is unavailable for any reason. When you are booted into the not-server OS, the server won;t be available.

Comment: Axiom: Data that is valuable to you is backed-up. Data that is not backed up must not be truly valuable to you. There are more threats to your data than a error during install.

Comment: Dual-booting a server doesn't make much sense if you plan to keep the server on all the time - there will not be an opportunity to boot into the other OS. I have done what you want to do, but asking "Please teach me how to set up a file server" is not a good question for here. If you can break it up into smaller questions, that might work.

Comment: You can run the system in a live environment ( it will run from the RAM ). No need installing an OS. If it already has an OS, why don't you use that? Is the user data on the same partition as that OS ( that is asking for trouble )?